# Javascript milliseconds notaion was not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
var current_date=new Date('2012/12/21 22:59:59.997');
var result=current_date.getTime();
```

Im not getting result in Firefox but it does show in chrome, in FF it shows invalid date.

Comment: As with pretty much any date format, you will only get it to work cross-browser when parsing it manually and feeding numbers in the `Date` constructor.

Comment: So what was the timezone of your date string, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following (using [`date.setMilliseconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds)):

```
var dateString = '2012/12/21 22:59:59.997';
var dateStringSplit = dateString.split('.');
var myDate = new Date(dateStringSplit[0]);
myDate.setMilliseconds(dateStringSplit[1]);
console.log(myDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and some other browsers (namely, Safari or Opera) don't like milliseconds.

```
// Split off the part after the dot
var current_date = new Date('2012/12/21 22:59:59.997'.split('.')[0]);

// Works everywhere!
var result = current_date.getTime();
```

If you really want to work with milliseconds, you have to split the date in multiple parts and use `new Date()` with those. From MDN documentation, here are the options:

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

Or, as [h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987917/851498) says, you can use the second part of the split date and use `setMilliseconds`.

Overall, you have plenty of solutions. Choose the one that annoys you the least.

Comment: What about the timezone? On different timezone it will give different result.

Comment: So? That's not the matter here.

Comment: I am in GMT+5.30. The result gives me 1356110999000. Let me know what you get!

Comment: @closure I'm in CET (GMT+1) and I get: 1356127199000 (4.5 hours difference from your result)

Comment: So? That's not the matter **here**.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I wholeheartedly agree - I just answered the question. No need to get defensive. :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I was talking to closure :)

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is not a standard format for [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

You may want to split the string and set the parts individually. Also, please manage the time zone correctly as it is not apparent which timezone the date string is in.

Comment: Even the standard formats don't work cross-browser with `Date.parse` :-)